# Performing Wick Rotation to get Euclidean action of a scalar field

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, conventions, wick-rotation

I'm working with the signature $(+,-,-,-)$ and with a Minkowski space-time Lagrangian

$$
\mathcal{L}_M ~=~ \Psi^\dagger\left(i\partial_0 + \frac{\nabla^2}{2m}\right)\Psi.
$$
The Minkowski action is
$$
S_M ~=~ \int dt d^3x \mathcal{L}_M.
$$
I should obtain the Euclidean action by Wick rotation.

My question is about the way with that I should perform the Wick rotation. The topic is something has been already asked ([look here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135853/)). The problem is that the answer to the question is not satisfactory for me and for this special case.

Since the spacetime interval is defined by $ds^2 = dt^2 - d\vec{x}^2$, If I perform a Wick rotation (just rotating the time axis) I get a negative Euclidean interval.

1. What's the sense of that? What's the connection between physical actions calculated in two different signature?
2. I can perform the rotation with different signs $t =\pm i\tau$. I know that, if there exist any poles, I must choose the correct sign in order to not cross them. But in this case, apparently I can choose both and I get always the same negative euclidean interval but different results.

If I choose $ t = i\tau $ I get 
$$
S_M ~=~i\int_{+i\infty}^{-i\infty} d\tau d^3x \Psi^\dagger\left(i\frac{\partial}{\partial i\tau} + \frac{\nabla^2}{2m}\right)\Psi 
~=~ -i\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty}  d\tau d^3x \Psi^\dagger\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\nabla^2}{2m}\right)\Psi
$$

If I choose $ t = -i\tau $ I get
$$
S_M ~=~-i\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty} d\tau d^3x \Psi^\dagger\left(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial i\tau} + \frac{\nabla^2}{2m}\right)\Psi 
~=~ -i\int_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty}  d\tau d^3x \Psi^\dagger\left(-\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\nabla^2}{2m}\right)\Psi
$$

I think there is a *slight* difference that I don't understand

3. Is the Euclidean action defined by $S_M = i S_E$ or by $S_M = -iS_E$?

Answer (score 1):

For the Euclidean path integral to be convergent, the Boltzmann factor should be an exponentially decaying function of the scalar field $\phi$. This in turn dictates that the direction of the [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation). (It should perhaps be stressed that Wick rotation is not merely a renaming of time variables, but that it involves an actual deformation of the time-integration contour in the complex time plane.) Standard conventions for the Wick rotation are

$$\begin{align} 
-S_E~=~&iS_M, \cr 
t_E~=~&it_M, \cr 
{\cal L}_E~=~&-{\cal L}_M,\end{align} \tag{1} $$

where the subscripts $E$ and $M$ stand for Euclid and Minkowski, respectively. In OP's case
$$\begin{align} {\cal L}_M~=~&i\phi^{\ast}  \frac{d\phi}{dt_M}- {\cal V} ,\cr 
{\cal L}_E~=~&\phi^{\ast}  \frac{d\phi}{dt_E}+ {\cal V} ,\cr
{\cal V}~=~&\frac{1}{2m}\nabla\phi^{\ast}\cdot \nabla\phi .\end{align} \tag{2}$$
See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106292/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your field depends on $t$, $\Psi = \Psi (x,t)$. Therefore, when you perform the Wick rotation $t = i\tau$, you also Wick rotate to your field, and obtain an action for $\Psi(x,i\tau)$. In the second case, you obtain an action for $\Psi(x,-i\tau)$. Those are not the same $\Psi$'s.

Comment: Yes, it's true but the classical Euclidian action is the second I wrote with $\Psi = \Psi(x,t)$ not?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)dt=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(-t)dt$ and also
$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{df(t)}{dt}dt=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{df(-t)}{-dt}dt$